# Differences between built-in type default-value-initialization

Tags: c++

Is there any difference/advantage between using any of this ways of initialization of a variable?

```
float A = 0;
float B = float();
float C(0);

cout << A << endl
     << B << endl
     << C << endl
```

Of course, the result will be the same in the 3 cases:

```
0
0
0
```

Comment: I've changed the dupe target since you've updated the question.  It should answer all of your questions.

Comment: FYI, that last print you deleted is no garbage. It's required to be 1.